# RedirectRule with .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to the .htaccess file.

I want to make pretty URLs but the server always gives me 404 or 500 errors.

For example, I want to redirect

`http://www.example.com/dir1`

to

`http://www.example.com/dir1/file1.html`

without showing `file1.html` in the address bar.

I've tried

`RedirectRule /dir1/$ /dir1/file1.html` but the server says `404`.

The `.htaccess` is in root.

What should I do?

Comment: It's a similar issue here.
[Apache redirect by without URL rewriting](http://serverfault.com/questions/160047/apache-redirect-by-without-url-rewriting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /   

RedirectRule ^dir1/?$ dir1/file1.html [L,NC]
```

OR use this rule in `/dir1/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dir1/

RedirectRule ^/?$ file1.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This htaccess rule will do the trick.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /   

RedirectRule ^dir1/?$ dir1/file1.html [L]
```

For the record the terminating `/?` means that you to redirect links with `/dir1` and links with `/dir1/`